# SQL with <> tags creating a problem. looking for alternative code/way

Tags: sql, xml, search, stored-procedures, nodes

I have a stored procedure with code like this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TESTTAGISSUE]  @rule nvarchar(30), @filter nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Split char(1),
   @X xml,
   @insertedguid uniqueidentifier,
   @insertedTime datetime
--
--  MYDBTITLE
--
IF(@rule='TESTGET')
BEGIN
  SET @Split = ' '
  SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s>' + REPLACE(@filter,@Split,'</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> ')

  ;with cte1 as (
   SELECT SearchItems = '%'+T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')+'%'
   FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)
  )
  SELECT Top 1  MYDB.* 
  FROM MYDB WITH(NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN cte1 on MYDB.MYDBTitle like SearchItems
  AND MYDB.Category IS NOT NULL
END
END
```

The objective of the code is to find the top result with the most matches.  Seems to work, but any way to do this without < or > in the code? Maybe any way to escape or encode them?

sample run:

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[TESTTAGISSUE]
        @rule = N'TESTGET',
        @filter = N'solid pine'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

The code is working great. However, a bit of unique/hack issue is we are using some custom tool to edit our SQL and it's not liking < or > in the code. We are looking at fixing that tool, but also wondering about this SQL and a cleaner way to do this same task?

Comment: If the code is working, find a better editing tool.

Comment: Not clear, but it looks your custom tool saves the code in XML. If that's the case, escape `<>` like `&lt;>`. Or just fix your custom tool to do this automatically.

Comment: Hell Bent, What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: sorry this was an issue with the tool and html . we fixed it but after further review it appears that XML code is not even necessary, we can use substring/charindex/LEN code